# How to call a screen which is a sibling to parent screen from a child? (please look at the image provided)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have been using react-native for building an app and facing an issue with navigation. I am using react-navigation where i have stack navigator with tanks and filter screens. And tanks screen has a tab navigator with map and lists screens as shown in the below picture.[image: Image for reference]

As the red line indications i am not able to navigate to filter screen from either maps or lists. Sorry for not providing a direction of flow.

i have tried this.props.navigation.navigate('filterScreen'); from maps and lists but it doesn't work (i know this will not work but still gave a tried).

Is there any way to navigate? Any lead would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:
 stack of tanks(the upper most screen)

```
export const Tank = StackNavigator({
 tankScreen: { screen: TankScreen },
 filterScreen: { screen : FilterScreen },
});
```

InnerTab represents tab navigator of tanks screen.

```
export const InnerTab = TabNavigator({
    Map: {
        screen: MapStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Map',
            tabBarIcon: ( 
                (Platform.OS === 'ios') ?  <Image source={require('../logos/map.png')}
                    style={[styles.icon, {
                        right: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 4),
                    }]}
                /> :  <Image source={require('../logos/map.png')}
                style={[styles.innerTabIcon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
         />
            )
        },
    },
    List: {
        screen: ListStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'List',
            tabBarIcon: (
                (Platform.OS === 'ios') ?   <Image source={require('../logos/list.png')}
                    style={[styles.icon, {
                        right: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 4),
                    }]}
                /> :   <Image source={require('../logos/list.png')}
                style={[styles.innerTabIcon, {color: '#ffffff'}]} />
            )
        },
    },
},
```

Please note that the screens in InnerTab are not stacks.

Comment: Calling `navigate('filterScreen')` (assuming that's the name you gave it in the configuration of the stack navigator) should actually work. Can you share the navigation wiring code?

Comment: I have added the code. Can you give it a look please #Kraylog

Comment: I think I know what's going on. Did you hook up the router from the inner tab navigator to the outer stack navigator?

Comment: Yes, i have used innerTab in tankScreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a screen in your `TabNavigator` to be able to navigate your `StackNavigator`, they need to be in the same navigation tree.

This is automatic when the screen definition is a navigator.

In your case, however, the screen is a component with a navigator inside.

To connect between the two, your component needs to expose the router of the tab navigator, and pass along the navigation state:

```
class TanksScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <InnerTab navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
TanksScreen.router = InnerTab.router;
```

See [Nesting a Navigator in a Component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting#Nesting-a-Navigator-in-a-Component).

Comment: Thank you so much @Kraylog , i have gone through the react navigation docs but missed this part. Now i realised the importance of reading docs completely.. Thanks again and your solution solved my issue.